# Parse.com adding parseObject to database exception: Expected number, but got an array

Tags: android, arrays, parse-platform, android-studio

I have the following code:

```
buttonAddAlert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(AddAlert.this.isOnline()){   
                    if(busNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty() || description.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                        Toast.makeText((Context)(AddAlert.this.getBaseContext()), (CharSequence)("Please fill all the fields!"), (int)(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("AlertsClass");
                        parseObject.add("BusNumber", Integer.parseInt(busNumber.getText().toString()));
                        parseObject.add("Description", description.getText().toString());
                        //requestLocation();
                        parseObject.add("Coordinates", new ParseGeoPoint(currentLatitude, currentLongitude));

                        parseObject.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                Intent recentSightingsPageIntent = new Intent(AddAlert.this, RecentSightings.class);
                                startActivity(recentSightingsPageIntent);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText((Context)(AddAlert.this.getBaseContext()), (CharSequence)("Your internet connection is offline"), (int)(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

As I am debugging the code, when it reaches the "public void done(ParseException e)" the exception(e) prints:

> > com.parse.ParseException: invalid type for key BusNumber, expected number, but got array.

I am a bit blindfolded, and i cannot see why I am receiving this error, because i am converting the text from the EditText to int, and still it says it is an array.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: what happens if you before that create an int variable then use that int variable as the value

Comment: Nope, i created the int variable, but got the same error.

Comment: Try with Integer.valueOf(busNumber.getText().toString()));

Answer (score 9):

Solved it. The problem was that i was using parseObject.add(which is used for arrays). To put a single value the database, you need to use parseObject.put(which is used for a single item). Otherwise you will get my exception. I am writing this here, maybe someone will see it with the same problem.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `addObject:forKey:`. The parse Object is actually dictionary so try using `setObject:forKey:`